# Clone a limited multi-dimensional

Tags: java, arrays

I have this:

```
String[][] numbers = {
     {"one", "two", "three"},
     {"four", "five", "six"},
     {"seven", "eight", "nine"}
}

String[][] tmp;
```

What i what now is that i clone numbers into tmp but LIMITED to 2 arguments per row. I don't wanna initialize any size

Output of tmp:

```
{      
    {"one", "two"},         
    {"four", "five"},         
    {"seven", "eight"}
}
```

What i tried:

```
String[][] cloneArray(String[][] elements) {
    int length = elements.length;
    String[][] target = new String[length][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(elements[i], 0, target[i], 0, elements[i].length);
    }

    return target;
}
```

I can't give a particular size becouse i have a function that updates(adds) the array:

```
String[][] append(String[][] arr, String[] element) {
    final int N = arr.length;
    arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, N + 1);
    arr[N] = element;
    return arr;
}
```

I get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: "I don't wanna initialize any size" - why not? You'd have to define the size of the target array anyway (i.e. limit it to `2` elements).

Comment: What is your question? In particular: what is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: becouse i have another function that add elements every time a button is pressed...so i need an unlimited array...i will edit the post

Comment: i get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 3):

We can filter out the inner array beyond the second element, by getting a `Stream<String[]>` out of it and applying the `Stream#map` on it so that the size of the new inner array is limited to 2 elements:

```
String[][] numbers = {
                       {"one", "two", "three"},
                       {"four", "five", "six"},
                       {"seven", "eight", "nine"}
                     };
String[][] tmp = Arrays.stream(numbers)
                        .map(arr -> (arr != null && arr.length > 2)
                                         ? Arrays.copyOf(arr, 2) 
                                         : arr)
                       .toArray(String[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tmp));
```

Output:

```
 [[one, two], [four, five], [seven, eight]]
```

Comment: @RaylessTiKi Glad it worked, please accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong syntax for `System.arraycopy()`. The declaration of the method is like this:

> public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)

Where, `src` and `dest` are source array and destination array respectively. The `arraycopy` function itself handles the position from `srcPos` to `srcPos + length` and copy it from `destPos` to `destPos + length`. So, no need to loop through the elements and use `arraycopy()` for each of them.

So, for your code, the fix will be:

```
String[][] cloneArray(String[][] elements) {
    int length = elements.length;
    String[][] target = new String[length][2];
    System.arraycopy(elements, 0, target, 0, elements.length);
    return target;
}
```

And if you don't want to use `arraycopy` rather want to loop through the elements and manually copy elements, you can also do that simply:

```
String[][] cloneArray(String[][] elements) {
    int length = elements.length;
    String[][] target = new String[length][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            target[i][j] = elements[i][j];
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: with your solution i don't get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException anymore, but it's not working...i get a very strange output

Comment: @RaylessTiKi Please check out my latest edit, this should work.